# Recursive CTE Table - Calculating EWMA (EMA) - How to optimize/refactor this code so it doesn't get killed by TDWM every time?

Tags: sql, recursion, statistics, teradata, common-table-expression

I've created a query that is making CTE tables, two are non-recursive and one is recursive in order to calculate exponential weighted moving average (EMA).
When I run my code in Teradata it gets killed by TDWM after some time.

Any ideas how to improve/work around this?

```
WITH 

smooth AS (
    SELECT CAST(0.741870935 AS NUMERIC (20,5)) AS alpha
),

numbered AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY customer_name, closed_date) as rn,  
        customer, 
        closed_date, 
        metric

    FROM my_table
),

recursive EWMA AS (
    SELECT rn, customer, closed_date, metric, CAST(metric AS NUMERIC(20,5)) as EWMA
    FROM numbered
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT numbered.rn, numbered.customer, numbered.closed_date, numbered.metric,
    smooth.alpha * numbered.metric + (1-smooth.alpha) * EWMA.EWMA
    FROM EWMA
    JOIN numbered
    ON EWMA.rn + 1 = numbered.rn
    CROSS JOIN smooth   
)

SELECT * FROM EWMA
ORDER BY closed_date;
```

Comment: What's your Teradata release? *16.20 Feature Upgrade 2* supports a new Moving Average function https://docs.teradata.com/reader/CWVY0AJy8wyyf7Sm0EsK~w/~GRekcSxM79AHBZcIlVyGA

Comment: I might try replacing your `numbered` CTE with a volatile table. Not certain how Teradata would handle this the way you've written it, but potentially it's running that CTE for every row in your `EWMA` cte.

Comment: You probably want `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY closed_date) as rn`, otherwise your code is like a cursor processing **all** rows sequentially. And as Andrew said, materializing `numbered` with a `Primary Index(customer,rn)` willprevent recalculating the ROW_NUMBER over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `depth` field to restrict the recursion?  Something like:

```sql
WITH smooth AS (...),
numbered AS (...),
recursive EWMA AS (
  SELECT 
    rn, customer, closed_date, metric, CAST(metric AS NUMERIC(20,5)) as EWMA, 
    1 AS depth
  FROM numbered
  WHERE rn = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    numbered.rn, numbered.customer, numbered.closed_date, numbered.metric,
    smooth.alpha * numbered.metric + (1-smooth.alpha) * EWMA.EWMA, 
    EWMA.Depth + 1 AS Depth
  FROM EWMA
  INNER JOIN numbered ON EWMA.rn + 1 = numbered.rn
  CROSS JOIN smooth   
  WHERE depth <= 10 -- Restrict recursion
)
SELECT * 
FROM EWMA
ORDER BY closed_date;
```

The recursive join with `numbered` may be causing the issue, assuming the `my_table` table is very large.  Ideally, you'd want to do a straight equality join on PI columns -- i.e. `table1.pi_col1 = table2.pi_col2`.  Not sure how using the `+1` expression is going to affect the join.

Looking at your query from a high-level, it seems like you just want to use the previous row's value in the current row's calculation.  If that's the case, then you could do away with the recursive CTE altogether and just use a `LAG()` window function:

```sql
WITH smooth AS (
  SELECT CAST(0.741870935 AS NUMERIC (20,5)) AS alpha
)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY customer_name, closed_date) as rn, -- row number
  customer, 
  closed_date, 
  metric,
  CAST(
    COALESCE(
      (smooth.alpha * metric + (1-smooth.alpha)) * -- current row's value
      LAG((smooth.alpha * metric + (1-smooth.alpha))) OVER(
        ORDER BY customer_name, closed_date) -- previous row's value
      , metric -- handle first row (no previous "EWMA" value)
    )
  AS NUMERIC(20,5)) AS EWMA
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thanks @ravioli, just modified it depth condition to: WHERE depth >= depth - 10
so it takes 10 previous row in consideration as adding weight to them.

 This helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  Did you try the second query too?  If that is the logic you're looking for, then that one may be better -- possibly faster, and no recursion limit.

Comment: I actually pulled the data set into Alteryx as the tool is caching the tables and the performance of queries has been so much better.

I've tried the other query, but the issue is that with LAG we're getting only previous row, and we need calculation to go recursively through at least 100 previous rows.

Either way this helped me a lot, thank you @ravioli !

Comment: Oops, you're right -- the `LAG` doesn't account for the previous rows.  Maybe check Dieter's suggestion above about the moving average function.  That may be what you're looking for.